# finding duplicate in a table with a condition

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery

I have a query such as this:

```
select a.id, a.color, a.shade from colors a where a.color = 'red'
```

which fetches

```
ID     | Color      | shade
-------|------------|---------
23     |red         | dark10
525    |red         | light-10
```

**Question:**

How can I find all records in table `colors` where there are multiple (two) occurrences of same`color` AND their corresponding shades are NOT identical

e.g. records like the following will not be considered

```
ID     | Color      | shade
-------|------------|---------
23     |green       | light-10
324    |green       | light-10
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by utilizing a GROUP BY clause with a HAVING COUNT(*) = 1 condition:

```
declare @colors table (
    id int,
    color nvarchar(100),
    shade nvarchar(100)
)

insert into @colors
        select 23, 'red', 'dark10'
union all select 525, 'red', 'light-10'
union all select 23, 'green', 'light-10'
union all select 324, 'green', 'light-10'

select c.*
from @colors c
inner join (
    select color, shade
    from @colors 
    group by color, shade
    having COUNT(*) > 1
) x
    on x.color = c.color
    and x.shade <> c.shade
```

Comment: I've corrected your answer relative to the question. I'll accept your answer. thanks

Comment: Thanks - I didn't have a ton of data to test on, so I appreciate you updating it.